# Definition of Haar systems, especially for groupoids $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, haar-measure, groupoids

In A Groupoid approach to $C^*$-algebras Jean Renault introduces left Haar systems. Say $G$ is a groupoid. Let $\Lambda=\{\mu^u,\,\,:\,\,u\in G^0\}$ be a family of Haar measures on $G$. Renault requires that the support of $\mu^u$ equals $G^u$, or in other words say $t$ is the target map then $t^{-1}(u)=\text{supp}(\mu^u)$. Yet I don't really see how this works as $t^{-1}(u)$ only consists of one set, has any one seen this definition before and can help me get some intuition for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Yet I don't really see how this works as $t^{-1}(u)$ only consists of one set"? The fibers $t^{-1}(u)$ as $u$ ranges over the unit space are a partition of $G$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it clarifies it already a bit, I am confused that the support can only consist of one set for me this seems like a weird condition for a measure.

Comment: What would it mean for the support of a measure to consist of more than one set?

Comment: Then it should be zero for all the other measurable sets.

Comment: You might prefer to not think of each $\mu^u$ as a measure on all of $G$ supported on $t^{-1}(u)$ and instead think it as a measure on $t^{-1}(u)$, which is basically the same thing. So you have a family of measures, each defined on a different part of a partition of $G$.

Comment: Regarding your comment "then it should be zero for all the other measurable sets", I'm not sure you are correctly understanding what the support of a measure means. Say $\mu$ is a measure defined on a sigma algebra $\mathcal{M}$. The support of $\mu$ is **not** the set of all $E \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(E) \neq 0$, as you may be thinking.

Comment: Ah yes, that is where I got confused. I tought the support of a measure $\lambda$ was supp$\lambda=\overline{\{A\in \mathcal{M}: \lambda(A)>0\}}$, I gues it makes sense to think about it as $\overline{\{x\in X| x\in A\in \mathcal{M}\,\,\lambda(A)>0\}}$... I hope I am now correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: The second thing you write is still not the correct definition of the support of a measure. Say $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space (set, sigma algebra, measure). As long as the measure is not the zero measure, every point $x \in X$ has $x \in X$ and $\mu(X) >0$ so, if we used what you wrote, we would conclude that every $x$ belongs to the support of $\mu$.